# Split array into pieces in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I woutld like to split an array into equal pieces like this:

```
 a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
 n = 2;
 b = split(a, n);

 b =

 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
```

Which function can do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
reshape (a, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This actually does not give the output asked in the question. It has to be `reshape(a,3,2)'`.

Comment: @Ze Ji Is there any function to join the matrices again after reshaping?

Answer (score 13):

If `a` can be divided by `n` you can actually provide only one argument to RESHAPE.

To reshape to 2 rows:

```
b = reshape(a,2,[])
```

To reshape to 2 columns:

```
b = reshape(a,[],2)
```

Note that reshape works by columns, it fills the 1st column first, then 2nd, and so on. To get the desired output you have to reshape into 2 columns and then transpose the result.

```
b = reshape(a,[],2)'
```

You can place a check before reshape:

```
assert(mod(numel(a),n)==0,'a does not divide to n')
```

Comment: Is there any function to join the matrices again after reshaping?

Comment: What matrices are you talking about? Sure, you can reshape back to the original vector: `a2 = reshape(b',1,[]);`

Comment: Is it possible to do a reshape where `a/n ~= int` and then back fill the end with zeros or NaN?

Comment: You have to fill the vector by appropriate number of NaNs first, so it becomes reshapable: `nn = floor(numel(a)/n)-mod(numel(a)/n); a2 = [a, nan(1,nn)];` (Didn't test it.)