# Divide matrix into smaller matrix

Tags: matlab

Consider i have an 1 dimension matrix:
    <1*50 double>

Now I want to divide into:
    <1*25 double>
    <1*25 double>

How can do that in matlab? Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to _split_ your matrix into 2 smaller ones. If yes consider editing the title of your question. The word 'divide' is ambiguous in this context.

Comment: What would be the advantage of splitting 1 variable into 2 variables? What are you planning to do? Maybe what you want is to create a 2x25-Matrix from it. If so: have a look ``reshape()``, so each row of the Matrix can still be adressed easily.

Comment: No @Hoki, it's just an example. I hope i can split matrix into n smaller, which n is according to me.

Comment: Example please @Nras?

Comment: You should be able to make your own example by typing "help reshape", then trying the function at the command line.

Comment: Well an example: ``A = 1:50; B = reshape(A,25,2)';`` Now your new "variables" are the rows of B: ``B(1,:)`` (it is 1 to 25) and ``B(2,:)`` (it is 26 to 50). With this method you can reshape the 1 to 50 vector A into any rectangular shape, which contains 50 elements and they are all adressable nicely and easily in loops and what not, where the i-th variable is ``B(i,:)``. This is way more handy than creating Variables ``B1``, ``B2``, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

```
A=ones(1,50)
```

Then splitting can be done as follows:

```
A1 = A(1:25)
A2 = A(26:end)
```

or, more generally

```
 A1 = A(1:floor(end/2)
 A2 = A(floor(end/2)+1:end)
```

or, even more generally for division in `n` arrays

```
for i=1:n
  A{i}=A(floor((end/n)*(i-1)+1):ceil((end/n)*i))
end
```

or something along those lines.

Furthermore, you could do something like [Split array into pieces in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615814/split-array-into-pieces-in-matlab) and then convert the result to a cell array.

Comment: thanks @sanchises, but if i want a loop for that, example i want struct X that contain <1*25 double> <1*25 double>. Can you help?

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but you can actually do: `A(1:floor(end/2))` and `A(ceil(end/2):end)`, no need for `length`. =)

Comment: @RobertP. ...well of course, I'll edit that right away. Silly of me to forget. Furthermore, the distinction between floor and ceil is only valid if the size of the array is odd, else you'll end up with the `end/2'th` element twice